# How to auto-adjust a HTML DIV down to bottom of a web page?

Tags: html, positioning

I'm struggling to auto-adjust a HTML DIV down to the bottom of a page:

```html
<div style='position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; font-size:10vmin; background:orange'>

  <header style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:26px; font:11px/24px Arial; border:none; color:#2E3F58; background:#B1DBFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;">Header 1</header>

  <button type="button" style="display:inline-flex; align-items:center; font:11px/24px Arial; border:none; color:black; background:none; cursor:pointer; outline:0 !important">Header 2</button>

  <table style="height:26px; width:100%; color:#FFF; background:red"></table>

  <div id="content" style="text-align:center; color:silver; font-size:10vmin; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background:green">content</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0nx9zbmt/

This is the part that doesn't adjust to bottom as I'd like to to do, so the entire lower part of the web page becomes green:

```
<div id="content" style="text-align:center; color:silver; font-size:10vmin; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background:green">content</div>
```

Any ideas? I'm new to the flex box model and fail to use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use     `height: 100%;` to the content div

```
<div id="content" style="height: 100%; text-align:center; color:silver; font-size:10vmin; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background:green">content</div>
```

Note: try to use `CSS` classes instead of inline `CSS` so it will look cleaner and easy to understand the code.

also  `top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;` will not have effect without position property.

Comment: Thanks, but then I'm getting a scrollbar at the right side which is not intended.

Comment: then you need to minus the height of header 1 header 2 and red(table) section loke this: height: calc(100% - 90px); set this to content div instead of 100%

Answer (score -1):

If you need to adjust the position of an element, You must add `position: relative;`, `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` to the element's styles. Otherwise your `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` values will be ignored.

In your case. You can add `position: absolute;` because you are giving it an absolute position. Also you need to remove that `top: 0;` because you aren't setting any value for `top`. You just need it to be at bottom.

So this is your final code.

```html
<div style='position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; font-size:10vmin; background:orange'>

<header style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:26px; font:11px/24px Arial; border:none; color:#2E3F58; background:#B1DBFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;">Header 1</header>

<button type="button" style="display:inline-flex; align-items:center; font:11px/24px Arial; border:none; color:black; background:none; cursor:pointer; outline:0 !important">Header 2</button>

<table style="height:26px; width:100%; color:#FFF; background:red"></table>

<div id="content" style="text-align:center; color:silver; font-size:10vmin; position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; background:green;">content</div>

</div>
```

More about css `position` : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: When I run your code there is an orange section between the red table and the green content div. I meant the entire lower part to become green below the red table.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add `width: 100%` and get rid of all the positioning. So the green element will get all the space left.